# Reading data from multiple data source type solution

Tags: data-connections

I have some data in different data souses like SQL server, Oracle and even some from web service. I want to access them from my new application. Is there any data connector that can help me doing it without writing code for creating/changing data structure?
My project is in visual studio (C#) so I can write different adapters myself but then I have to write methods for each entity and keep them up to date if there was a change.

I've looked at Kafka (confluent platform) but it seems to be suitable only for streaming. There was some data connectors written by Telerik but it has some limitations like it cannot use Compound primary keys.

I appreciate any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've searched a lot for this and I did not find a solution to answer all needs.

There are some data connectors like Teleriks data connector that you can use to use as a adapter for the sql data base, etc. But all in all, I think it makes sense to write your own adapters most of the times. 
For collecting the data, I strongly recommend to use a message broker in between since it is connecting external systems